# Intuition behind definition of the Lebesgue integral.

Tags: measure-theory

I am having trouble intuitively understanding the definition of the Lebesgue integral for non-negative measurable functions. The definition is below:

$$\int_\Omega f(\omega) \mu(d\omega) = sup\{\int_\Omega \phi(\omega) \mu(d\omega) : 0\leq \phi \leq f, \phi \in \mathcal{E_+} \}$$
Where $\mathcal{E_+}$ is the set of non-negative simple functions defined on $\Omega$. I don't quite understand what the sup is being taken over, and why this is a good way to define the integral. Any intuition is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The $\sup$ is being taken over all $\phi$s which are in $\mathcal{E}_+$ and which are between $0$ and $f$ - basically, the integral of $f$ is defined as the "approximations from below" by simple functions, and since we're approximating from below we want to take a $\sup$. Does that make sense to start?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes that certainly makes sense to start, and thank you for your quick response! This is in line with my reading, as I have read that given such an $f$ I can always find a sequence $\{\phi_n\}_n, \phi_i \in \mathcal{E_+}$, such that $\phi_n \uparrow f$, pointwisely. However, I am having trouble seeing why pointwise convergence is enough to approximate an integral over all of $\Omega$. Can you please explain what I might be missing in my thinking.

Comment: hard to explain this in a forum. Take 2-3 books about the Lebesgue integral to find a way to understand it. Indeed Lebesgue integral, and measure theory in general, is very intuitive and understandable

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks for your message! I am using Resnick and Durrett to teach myself these concepts now. I am trying to build up my intuition, so any thoughts you have are welcome.

Comment: @Matt the idea of any integral holds in some kind of limit or approximation. You have a sequence of functions that approximate, in some sense, your function, and for each of these functions the notion of integral is clearly defined, so you can try to define an integral to your desired function as a limit of integrals, such that each integrand is closer and closer to your function, after you need to see if your definition works, that is, if its well-defined. The supremum is a way to represent the integral of Lebesgue, but there are a lot of equivalent ways to do it

Comment: (continues) one way to do it is, by example, defining a normed space of functions such that the norm is given by an integral that its easy to understand intuitively, in this case the space of simple functions. Now, it can be shown that any normed space can be completed to a Banach space, in this case the completion of the space of simple functions is named the $L_1$ space, and any function there is the limit of a Cauchy sequence of simple functions. It can also be shown that this description is equivalent, with some caveat, to the given by the supremum